# Jquery loop through Json with array of objects and get key name

Tags: jquery, json

I am able to read a json array from php, i want to display the key name of the items aswell. This might not make sense now but please check  below code.

**My json data**

```
{ "A":{"Africa":"201455632", "Asia":"5145000"}, 
  "B":{"Brasil":"68455222"},
  "C":{"China":"14546787"}
 }
```

**My js code** i am able to dislplay the key-val pair

```
 $.each(data, function() {
     console.log('---')
     $.each(this, function(k, v) {
      console.log(k, v)
     });
 });
```

Its displays like this

```
  ---
  Africa 201455632
  Asia 5145000 
  ---
  Brasil 68455222 
  ---
  China 14546787
```

My Problem is, i want to display it like this, with their key name aswell, what can i replace console.log('---') with

```
A
  Africa 201455632
  Asia 5145000
B
  Brasil 68455222
C
  China 14546787
```

Comment: You need a nested each function to reach the data you want.

Comment: Do the same thing you did in the inner loop.  `$.each(data, function(key, val) {}`

Answer (score 5):

Use the parameters to the callback function (just like you did with the inner loop).

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key);
    $.each(value, function(k, v) {
        console.log('  ' + k, v);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fr8oL9x/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
     console.log(key)
     $.each(value, function(k, v) {
      console.log(k, v)
     });
 });
```

Hope its help.

Comment: This looks like you just copied and pasted @John S's answer.

Comment: I started 10 minutes ago, bad luck for my. But i don't copy paste anything. Sory bad english.

Comment: 5 min is enough time to review what others have answered. If you had a slightly different solution, or offered something else of value, I wouldnt downvote (possibly even upvote instead.) You should also *explain* (as John did) what it is about your answer that solves the problem - not just post code. For those reasons, and my initial comment, sorry, but I'm giving this a downvote.

Comment: Sorry for the answer, its my second or third, i will check the answers next time before posting it. No problem for the downvote, just explaining what i do.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Juan - While an explanation is not a requirement, it helps to follow Gunr's advice. Following the advice helps ensure the community does not negatively receive the answer. And your English is fine - its much better than my Spanish.

Comment: Thanks @jww. Im learning this new stuff and appreciate your help. I will try to do a better answer.